# How to add new lines after HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple method for adding input boxes after a button is clicked. The goal of this method is to generate a set of input boxes with a newline inserted after each div.

[image]

In the screenshot above you can see that the divs are spaced properly. However, when the add_more button is clicked the generated inputs do not come out properly.

Expected:
The code should generate new input boxes like so:

```
                      <div>
                        Key Term 2: <input id="el2" type="text" value=""> <br>
                      </div>
                      <br>
```

Actual:

```js
function add_more() {
  // we've added more inputs.
  addMore = true;

  // set html generated to false, because new inputs have been added.
  htmlGenerated = false;

  // increment the number of inputs.
  numberOfInputs++;

  //fetch the input boxes.
  inputs = document.getElementById("inputBoxes");

  // create newline
  br_key = document.createElement("br");

  // create newline
  br_description = document.createElement("br");

  //create a new row for a key term.
  row = document.createElement("div");

  // set the key term text.
  row.innerHTML = "Key Term ";
  row.innerHTML += numberOfInputs;
  row.innerHTML += " :";

  // create the input for the key.
  key = document.createElement("input");
  key.setAttribute("id", "el" + numberOfInputs);

  //add the key to the row.
  row.appendChild(key);
  row.after(br_key);

  //create a row for the new description.
  row2 = document.createElement("div");

  // set the description text.
  row2.innerHTML = "Description  "
  row2.innerHTML += numberOfInputs;
  row2.innerHTML += " :";

  // create the description input
  description = document.createElement("input");
  description.setAttribute("id", "dl" + numberOfInputs);

  // add the description to the row.
  row2.appendChild(description);
  row2.after(br_description);

  // add the rows for the key and the description to the inputBoxes.
  inputs.appendChild(row);
  inputs.appendChild(row2);
}
```

```html
<div>Key Term 5 :<input id="el5"></div>
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Side note: you should avoid doing `innerHTML+=` a lot, as that way you are going to do a lot of reparsing the same text.

Comment: Protip: Don't use line breaks for layout. That's not what they're for. Use spacing on your wrapper divs (which are already block-level) instead.

Comment: Why don't you just use CSS to do this? It's generally bad practice to use markup for layout

Comment: Protip: Your inputs require labels for accessibility. You should be wrapping the text with `label` elements and linking them with the `for` attribute.

Comment: Please enhance the snippet to correct the error and show the problem.

Comment: @Liam how do you do it in css?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is essentially incorrect HTML, CSS. I'd implement your inputs, etc. like this:

```css
.full-width-label {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<label class="full-width-label" for="1">Label</label>
<input type="text" id="1"/>
```

There are multiple ways to achieve the above, this is just one of your options but now you no longer need to embed the look into the HTML and the format of your HTML (line breaks) is independent of your look.

You might want to look into an off the shelf solution for these kinds of things, like [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) or [Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/)

Answer (score -1):

You can use make it in a simple way

HTML

add this jquery cdn

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>

<button type="button">Click Here</button>
<div class="appendDiv">

</div>
```

Js

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
    var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
    var appendDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('appendDiv');
    var key = 1;
    var descKey = 1;

    $('button').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); 

      $(appendDiv).append('<div class="child"><div class="grand-child"><label>Key Form :'+ ' '+(++key)+'</label><input type="text" value=""/></div><div class="grand-child"></div><label>Description :'+ ' '+(++descKey )+'</label><input type="text" value=""/></div>');
   })
})
```

Comment: There are no jquery tags on this question. Please only add jQuery solutions to jquery questions

Comment: What about the JS that the guy has used. I showed him a simpler and efficient way to solve this issue. I did what I know. Please Mind your own Business. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Adding a whole library to do something that you can do without it, is not efficient. It's 2021, Jquery is a 2010 technology. It's pretty much redundant now